# Passing a class type as a parameter to a process in an external dll reference in C#

Tags: c#, class, reference, code-injection

I have the following code that errors on passing the ‘stockReportParameters’ in the call to the process in an external DLL:

```
{
        String accessToken = Helper.BearerToken(this.Url.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString());

        return await this.InventoryClient.GetStoreLevelReportAsync(accessToken, stockReportParameters, cancellationToken);
```

There is both a local and remote public class  ‘stockReportParameters’ both defined  as

```
    public class StockReportParameters
{ public List<Guid> Stores { get; set; } }
```

The error is:

> Argument 2: Cannot convert from {the local class} to {the remote
>   class}
>
> Argument Type {the local class} is not assignable to parameter type
>   {the remote class}

How do I pass the contents of this to the remote process?

Comment: Missing some info but I'm guessing it's a compile error? Then you are just passing something of the wrong type as the second parameter and it has nothing to do with "local" or "remote". Just because two unrelated classes in different namespaces have the same name and properties doesn't mean you can just assign one to the other. If GetStoreLevelReportAsync asks for "SomeNamespace.StockReportParameters" then you need a variable of that type, not "ADifferentNamespace.StockReportParameters".

Comment: Yes it's a compile error. So how can I pass this?

Answer (score 1):

"GetStoreLevelReportAsync" expects a parameter of type "{the remote class}" as you call it but "stockReportParameters" is of type "{the local class}". You can't just assign one to the other so you either have to change "stockReportParameters" to be of the type "{the remote class}" or use a new variable of type "{the remote class}" and copy the values of "stockReportParameters":

```
var remoteStockReportParameters = new [Insert "{the remote class here}"]();
remoteStockReportParameters.Stores = new List<Guid>(stockReportParameters.Stores);
return await this.InventoryClient.GetStoreLevelReportAsync(accessToken, remoteStockReportParameters, cancellationToken);
```